# How to implement UIRequiresPersistentWifi to work application in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, background-process

My application needs persistent wifi connection in the background, I think the only way to do is to apply `UIRequiresPersistentWifi` to info.plist file. So, below is what I have added to info.plist,

I added `UIRequiresPersistentWifi` with `YES`.

I added `Required device capabilities` with `wifi`

I created `NSInputStream`, `NSOutputStream` streams in code. Even after doing all these sockets does not work in the background. What else am I missing?

Should I add any code to `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` delegate method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we have to add code in `applicationDidEnterBackground` as below.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{        
        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```